# In what ways dragons can kill a person having Blood of the Dragon?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones, dragons

In what ways dragons can kill a person having Blood of the Dragon?

Obviously, there is:

> fire, that can't kill a person having Blood of the Dragon, as Daenerys say after the Viserys death from the melted gold.

Also, can dragons kill a person having Blood of the Dragon on their own will or only on demand?

Comment: your use of the term "Dragonborn" is a bit distracting. Since I don't think they ever use it in the novels or on the show, I keep thinking you're asking about *Skyrim*...

Comment: See this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/is-daenerys-targaryen-immune-to-fire

Comment: @Jaciq this isn't a dupe

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What is a "Dragonborn"?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic, didn't say it was, but I find the accepted answer quite relevant for this question also, seeing as how the asker thinks that fire can't hurt a "Dragonborn".

Comment: The actual quote Daenarys Targaryen uses is "He was no dragon. Fire cannot kill a dragon". So are you asking can fire kill a dragon? Or can fire kill a Targaryen?

Comment: m0nhawk, if by "Dragonborn" you meant "the Targaryen", you should clarify so. But even so, I must assume you understand dragons and fire *can* kill Targaryen, judging by your hidden spoiler.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 No. This question is about *A Song of Ice and Fire*, the series of fantasy books by George R.R. Martin. What "dragonborn" means in a completely unrelated computer game is not relevant here.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 But I didn't ask what "dragonborn" meant. I asked the OP if he/she was asking about the Targaryens (who are not "dragonborn", but they are the closest to dragon-anything we have in ASoIaF). In what way does your comment about an unrelated game answer this?

Comment: @AndresF. I can see I've struck a nerve, which was not my intention in the slightest so I'll delete all my comments. Apologies.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 You didn't strike a nerve and you've nothing to apologize for. It's just that your comment was simply completely unrelated to the question and unhelpful, and you replied to me something I didn't ask to begin with. Not offensive, just... puzzling.

Comment: You asked "what is a dragonborn?". I answered. I know it is not something found in A Song of Ice and Fire, and therefore not really relevant, but you did ask :)

Comment: @maguirenumber6 No. I asked what "dragonborn" meant in ASoIaF. I also added "if by Dragonborn you meant the Targaryen", which was what the OP meant and you chose to ignore. This question is also resolved. All of this means your late comment referencing an unrelated work of fantasy, even after the question as been answered (and closed as a dupe!) is extremely off-topic and unhelpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I don't remember any mention of 'Dragonborn' on either the books or the show.

Now, a dragon, besides the fire that he/she breathes, is a huge beast. It can easily:

- Eat the person
- Rip him/her from limb to limb
- Grab him, fly and let go of him/her whilst on mid-air
- Hit him with his/her giant legs

And many other similar ways.

> And can dragons kill Dragonborn on their own will or only on demand?

We don't know as of yet; if a dragon is pissed off, I don't doubt it can kill its 'owner'

Comment: Hehe, that sounds like the ancient black dragon in http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0638.html : “Silence! I will eat you ALIVE, flames or no flames!!”

Comment: As for the will, I do strongly believe dragons can kill their masters, otherwise, why would the Targaryens have a need for the DragonBinder horn.

Comment: There's one "dragonborne" in "The Princess and the Queen". Found it using http://asearchoficeandfire.com/ . ;-)

Comment: And last but not list..........as a huge besast just sit down on the person in question ;)

Answer (score 3):

The Targeryens (I assume that they are who you mean by 'Dragonborn'), are not immune to fire as stated multiple times by George RR Martin.
Via westeros.org

> some fans are reading too much into the scene in GAME OF THRONES where the dragons are born -- which is to say, it was never the case that all Targaryens are immune to all fire at all times.

From a chat...

> Granny, thanks for asking that. It gives me a chance to clear up a common misconception. TARGARYENS ARE NOT IMMUNE TO FIRE! The birth of Dany's dragons was unique, magical, wonderous, a miracle. She is called The Unburnt because she walked into the flames and lived. But her brother sure as hell wasn't immune to that molten gold.

In response to the followup question asking if Dany would survive the fire again.

> Probably not.

So a dragon can burn, bite, scratch, or sit on a Targeryen to kill them.

Comment: Just realized the answer to the question linked above uses these same quotes. Just goes to show how many times this myth has been debunked...