# Could wildfire burn Daenerys Targaryen?

Tags: game-of-thrones

It was established in the books by Word of God fairly early on that Daenerys Targaryen is *not* immune to fire. [From an interview with George RR Martin](http://www.dakkadakka.com/dakkaforum/posts/list/449541.page?userfilterid=33891):

> Granny: Do Targaryens become immune to fire once they "bond" to their dragons?
>
> George_RR_Martin: Granny, thanks for asking that. It gives me a chance to clear up a common misconception. TARGARYENS ARE NOT IMMUNE TO FIRE! The birth of Dany's dragons was unique, magical, wonderous, a miracle. She is called The Unburnt because she walked into the flames and lived. But her brother sure as hell wasn't immune to that molten gold.
>
> Revanshe: So she won't be able to do it again?
>
> George_RR_Martin: Probably not.

However, it seems that with the recent events of Episode 4 of Season 6 of the TV show, [*Book of the Stranger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Stranger), television Daenerys **is** immune to fire, burning down the main building in Vaes Dothrak with all of the Khals inside it, and walking outside naked but unharmed.

When the events of the season finale

> demonstrated the destructive force of wildfire once again with the destruction of the Great Sept of Baelor by Queen Cersei, and the imminent collision course between her and the Mother of Dragons,

it demands that the question be asked: could Daenerys survive being burnt by wildfire?

Editing to differentiate between this and the previous question. **Has it been established in the TV show that wildfire is hotter than regular fire?** All she has been exposed to so far (funeral pyre, burning great hall in Vaes Dothrak) was normal fire. Assuming the books and TV show follow different rules, this question is asking has there been any evidence that Daenerys, and Targaryens* in general are immune to fire to the point where being burnt by wildfire or dragon's fire would not hurt them. If there is insufficient evidence for this that would make the answer pure speculation I will close the question, but this community is excellent for digging up tiny details that may answer even the most esoteric questions.

*See spoiler:

> The relevance of this question I feel is even greater now that it's possible that there is more than one Targaryen left in the world, who has just taken up the mantle of The King in the North.

Comment: Answer: Probably not.

Comment: Targaryens are not immune to fire but unlike what Old George said in that Interview, Daenerys did show immunity to fire twice and is therefore likely to show it in the future as well especially now since the Show has passed all the restrictions of books realm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Daenerys avoid injury in Vaes Dothrak?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128586/how-did-daenerys-avoid-injury-in-vaes-dothrak) if books canon welcome, Opinion based if show-canon only

Comment: In show canon Daenerys never had to face Dragonfire. In books she faced Dragonfire and lived. Wildfire is still less hot than dragonfire. Btw, If your question is solely about show canon (Which sadly I just noticed) then it is opinion based and speculative. If it is books canon based, It is a duplicate.

Comment: As we can see in s01e09, Jon is not immune to fire (his hand was burnt a little in a battle with wight in Castle Black)

Comment: Daenyrs hasn't encountered Wildfire in the shows or books, so any answer will be opinion based.

Comment: Daenerys withstood fire on another occasion, in the [House of the Undying](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_the_Undying). She commanded the dragons to breath fire at their enemies with her still in the way. She wasn't engulfed, like the other two incidents, but she still made contact and she clearly was unaffected.

Comment: Is wildfire also meant to be a bit magic? Or am I just mistaking its greenness for an indication of sorcery?

Comment: Since there's nothing definitive, maybe we need to come at it from a different angle: are DRAGONS impervious to wildfire or no? That answer may help inform whether or not show-Dany is immune...

Comment: @Ace Human!=Dragon ....And Dragons should be immune to wildfire because dragonfire is hotter than wildfire

Comment: For some reason, I keep thinking of [Gorilla VS Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: Just remember, show != books.

Comment: She may survive the burning... but watch out for bells...

Answer (score 9):

### The Show-Books schism

Season 6 which you are citing is beyond the books and it is not unlikely that the whole event was invented by Dan Weiss and David Benioff instead of George R.R. Martin.

Writer of Season 6 Episode 4 was [Daniel Sackheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Sackheim), not George R.R. Martin. Since show at that point was ahead of the books, it is highly unlikely that George wrote that whole scenario.

### Wildfire's destructive powers

Wildfire is the second hottest fire in Planetos, right after dragonfire. But there are fires which burn even hotter than Dragonfire. It was written that on the day of Doom every hill for 500 miles had split asunder to fill the air with ash and smoke and fire, blazes so hot and hungry that even dragons in the sky were engulfed and consumed.

After Targaryen dragons died, wildfire was the source of their power. Its manufacturing is a secret which is guarded jealously by Guild of Pyromancers.

### Wildfire and Targaryens - A History

As of now, it would be mere speculation what the show runners want to do in the proposed scenario i.e. Dany Vs. Wildfire.

As George has made it clear numerous times, Targaryens aren't fireproof. There is a [whole bunch of Targaryens who died due to being burnt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133705/how-could-jon-be-burned/133756#133756).

Since your question is specifically about Wildfire, A Targaryen prince, Prince [Aerion Brightflame](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerion_Targaryen) once drank wildfire, hoping to be transformed into a dragon. He was instead transformed into a corpse. This is merely impact of drinking wildfire, imagine what would happen if he was to burn himself alive with it!

### Conclusion?

So based on the precedence, If one Targaryen could die because of Wildfire, why can't another? But bear in mind, Daenerys is special, more so in show than in  books.

So since it's speculation, I would argue that I see no reason why Daenerys shouldn't burn in Wildfire but I won't be surprised if she doesn't because that's obviously the idea Showrunners are trying to convey i.e. Daenerys can't be burnt, ever.

Comment: I think wildfire is special because it seems to have an explosive property and even if she doesn't burn, the explosive effect could kill her.

Answer (score 2):

### Daenerys is probably susceptible to wildfire.

Using visual evidence from the series, wildfire burns much hotter than normal fire or even dragon-fire.

> (Compare the effects of Drogon's fire on Kraznys mo Nakloz (the master who sold the Unsullied to Daenerys) to the effects of wildfire on the High Sparrow.

The latter evaporated almost instantaneously, while the former had plenty of time to suffer.  If wildfire really burns that much hotter than even dragon fire, there's not really any reason to suspect Daenerys would be immune.  However, it's possible that the CGI department is merely off the leash and misrepresenting the intended facts of the universe.

Comment: The comparison is not valid. Drogon was not an adult dragon back then. It was a child. It has been stated various times that Dragonfire is the hottest fire in the world and Wildfire comes after that. So sole premise of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Aegon If that's the case, do we have evidence that Daenerys is immune to adult Dragonfire?

Comment: @MartianInvader Not according to books, she isn't. She was burned by Drogon's fire. but she escaped with few burns

Comment: @MartianInvader Reading the comment again, it is kind of ambiguous (the comment). Let me clarify, from the books we do not have any evidence for such. On the contrary we have evidence that Daenerys can burn from fire, dragonfire to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world different kids inherit different qualities from different parents. So, it is quite possible that Danny was the only one to inherit the fire immunity. There's also a small possibility that the fire immunity is like a skill, Danny knows she can do it so she's immune to fire (can switch it on of sorts) so Jon might well have some dragon abilities he doesn't know of as well as his warging abilities inherited from the Stark side.

Comment: There is nothing like a "Fire immunity trait" running in Targaryen family so she definitely did not inherit it. Targaryens have burnt to death numerous times.

Answer (score 0):

Wildfire burned and killed King Aegon V Targaryen, and Prince Duncan during the tragedy at Summerhall.

So that's a resounding absolutely YES! Daenerys would be burnt to an unrecognizable crisp by wildfire.

And that's Canon.