# Is Jon Snow immune to fire?

Tags: game-of-thrones, jon-snow

We've seen his aunt survive all fire and I even remember she almost enjoyed the scalding bath.

Jon was resurrected by the fire god. Is Jon now immune to fire, and just doesn't know it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Daenerys Targaryen immune to fire?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/is-daenerys-targaryen-immune-to-fire)

Comment: I don't see the duplicate or how this is Opinion based? This should be left open

Comment: @Edlothiad Future Works possibly. But definitely POB because we have seen no evidence in either direction. Answers will be speculation.

Comment: How is this on hold again?! There are legitimate answers below... two of them... that have answered the question... with no opinions what so ever... before you all placed it on hold again... Chill with the on hold button people...

Comment: @amflare skooba's answer looks very sourced to me.

Comment: @Odin1806 this site is delete happy and close vote happy, welcome to the party :)

Comment: @Edlothiad I think every SE site is. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: @Edlothiad - Yeah and it completely ignores OP asking about anything after Jon came back to life. Which, coincidently, has no source for any answer either for or against.

Comment: Why would that change anything after he got resurrected?

Comment: Is it confirmed anywhere that she is imune to fire? I always considered the moment when she "birthes" the dragons to be a one time thing.

Comment: @ricardo Looking at the "out of context" link above about Dany being immune to fire in the author said that she was not immune except that one time with the dragons, but it seems the show is taking it to the extreme.

Comment: [Please stop editing the title of this question to meaningless nonsense.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as the books go, GRRM has said that even Daenerys is not immune to fire and surviving the pyre was a one-time thing related to the dragons.

In the show, Daenerys appears to be permanently immune, however we actually see Jon burned by the lamp that he uses to burn the wight in the Lord Commander's quarters -

So it would appear that he is not immune to fire as Daenerys is.

Edit: As for being a fire wight, we don't know much about what abilities this potentially comes with. We do know that Beric Dondarrion uses blood to light his sword, as seen when he fights the Hound. This may be because he is a fire wight, or he may be using some sort of blood magic.

It could be easy to assume that a fire wight would have fire immunity - after all, the definition given by GRRM is "a wight animated by fire," as opposed to ice. However this has not been confirmed in the show or in the books.

If being a fire wight does give you fire immunity, it could even be possible that Daenerys is a fire wight. After all, if she is not immune to fire because she is a Targaryen, why is she? This is all just speculation, so until they actually show Jon or Beric consumed by flame and left unscathed we really don't know.

Answer (score 38):

## NO.

Jon was burned by the fire he used to kill the wights in Season 1 that invaded Castle Black.

Quotes from the book, which since this is Season 1, the scenes in the show remain highly faithful to. The burns were quite severe and took weeks or months to heal properly.

> Jon plunged his hand into the flames, grabbed a fistful of the burning drapes, and whipped them at the dead man. Let it burn, he prayed as the cloth smothered the corpse, gods, please, please, let it burn.
>
> *A Game of Thrones - Jon VII*
>
> ...
>
> "You do not look well. How is your hand?"
>
> "Healing." Jon flexed his bandaged fingers to show him. **He had burned himself more badly than he knew** throwing the flaming drapes, and his right hand was swathed in silk halfway to the elbow. At the time he'd felt nothing; the agony had come after. **His cracked red skin oozed fluid, and fearsome blood blisters rose between his fingers, big as roaches.** "The maester says I'll have scars, but otherwise the hand should be as good as it was before."
>
> *A Game of Thrones - Jon VIII*
>
> ...
>
> He flexed his burned hand as he rode, opening and closing the scarred fingers. They still pained him, but it felt good to have the wrappings off.
>
> *A Game of Thrones - Jon IX*
>
> ...
>
> He gave Jon a long, searching look. "But we were speaking of hands. How is yours?"
>
> "Better." Jon peeled off his moleskin glove and showed him. **Scars covered his arm halfway to the elbow, and the mottled pink flesh still felt tight and tender, but it was healing.** "It itches, though. Maester Aemon says that's good. He gave me a salve to take with me when we ride."
>
> *A Clash of Kings - Jon I*

Comment: The question refers to events that have taken place since (Jon's resurrection as a 'fire wight'). We know from this that he wasn't immune to fire then, but as I read the question it's asking about things as they stand later. It's a good opening to an answer...

Answer (score 9):

## Probably not.

Only Daenerys has shown any kind of exceptional immunity to fire, while other Targaryens such as Viserys were not immune and died from fire/heat, suggesting this ability is not a Targaryen trait but specific to Daenerys.

Jon has been burned before when he fought off the first wight attack as Castle Black. He grabbed a lantern the wrong way and he appeared to recoil in pain as he did so. However, this was before he was resurrected and became a fire wight. We have no idea whether fire wights have any special immunity to fire.

Comment: To be clear, GRRM has stated that Dany is in no way immune to fire, with the events at the funeral pyre being a one-time magical event related to the dragons. So the show has diverged heavily from the book universe in this regard.

Answer (score -2):

No, his hand was burnt before in either season 1 or 2, I don't exactly remember, while he was killing a wight in castle black. 
As far as I know, in the books, the Targaryens can be burnt. This one is different from the books.

Comment: This is not adding anything new.