# Did Jon Snow try to take control of this character?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the Game of Thrones series finale, after

> Jon kills Dany

Drogon arrives at the scene, and Jon and Drogon have a bit of a staring contest before Drogon ultimately

> burns the Iron Throne while leaving Jon unharmed.

I can think of a couple of interpretations of what happened here:

1. During this "staring contest", Jon attempted to wield whatever manner of influence Targaryens have over dragons to get Drogon to submit to Jon and allow Jon to become his new master / rider, but failed. (But perhaps succeeded at the smaller feat of convincing Drogon not to kill him.)
2. Jon didn't even try to wield influence over Drogon in this scene. Perhaps he was too overcome with emotion as a result of what he had just done to try, or perhaps he just resolved to face the consequences of his actions, whether from Drogon or from Grey Worm and co.

Is there any evidence to support favouring one of these interpretations over the other? Is one of them more in character for Jon?

Answer (score 9):

There is no statement from anyone within the show as to whether or not Jon was trying to influence Drogon.

It seemed more like Jon was in acceptance of his crime, and was ready to face Drogon's anger and judgment. He had killed his lover and Drogon's mother, part of him probably thought he deserved to be punished by Drogon.